# Does OO Javascript have a `to_bool` or `__len__` equivalent?

Tags: javascript, oop, casting, boolean, instance

Does OO JS have a mechanism for casting instance objects to boolean? I would like to be able to use custom instance objects directly in conditionals, and make assertions along the lines of `!!(new Foo(0)) === false`, `!!(new Foo(1)) === true`.

- Python has `__nonzero__` and `__len__` (see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing))
- Ruby has `to_bool`.

How does JS do this for String literals `""` and zero `0`?

Comment: `!!(new Foo(1)) === true` that's fine. Javascript converts the objects `toString()` when you compare an object with another type.

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude what does it convert to string specifically?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude Would `!!(new Foo(1))` always return `true`?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: It doesn't do any conversions with `===`. With `==` it will depend on the other operand. If a boolean as you show, it'll convert the boolean to a number, and then the object will go through a `toPrimitive` operation, which involves `.toString()`. In your example, you've converting the object directly, so it's a simple `true === true` operation.

Comment: @squint you're right. My comment has sense with `!!(new Foo(1)) == true` but not with strict comparison. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: Almost. You'd need to drop the `!!` because it has precedence over the `==`, resulting in `true == true`. Without the `!!`, the `.toString()` will be invoked, so the OP could actually provide a custom `.toString()` function that may give a desired result in that circumstance.

Comment: nathanallen: Ultimately, no. There's no override for a boolean conversion. There is one for string conversion ( `.toString()` ), and one for a ToPrimitive operation ( `.toValue()` ), but neither are invoked during a boolean conversion.

Comment: ...unless [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) has something. I haven't studied that new feature yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, JS does not provide a trap method for casting to boolean. Truthiness of a value is [statically determined](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean) by the language rules and cannot be changed.

You should give your instances a method to be explicitly invoked like `isValid()`, `isTruthy()`, `isEmpty()` or whatever concept your object represents.

Comment: It looks like there is an internal mechanism for this ([toBoolean](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-toboolean)). Too bad it's not an exposed API!

Comment: @nathanallen: It's exposed as the `Boolean` function or by using `!!` (double negation operator).